# Change ConstraintLayout default margin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

When we create a constraint to a view through the designer, it automatically creates margin for this constraint - `8dp`. There are a lot of cases when I don't need that margin, so I have to manually remove it (or change to `0dp`).

Is there a way we can customize a default margin for a constraint in `ConstraintLayout` ?

Comment: you have to change it to `0dp`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For ConstraintLayout child's you can set default margin like is shown on the image.

[image]

Comment: I changed it to 16dp, but when I add new views on contraint layout it doesn't have anything on constraint widget or layout margin?